# Spring MVC 4.2.2 and Hibernate 5.0.2 giving error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-orm

Below are the dependency version details on the pom.xml

```
<!-- spring --> 
<org.springframework-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<org.springframework.data-version>1.11.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data-version>

<!-- hibernate --> 
<org.hibernate.hibernate-core>5.0.2.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-core> 
<org.hibernate.hibernate-annotations>3.5.6-Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-annotations> 
<org.hibernate.hibernate-commons-annotations>3.2.0.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-commons-annotations> 
<org.hibernate.hibernate-validator>5.2.2.Final</org.hibernate.hibernate-validator>
```

I'd picked the Hibernate version details from the "spring-orm" pom and found the Hibernate 5.0.2 is compatible with Spring 4.2.2

With the same dependencies in-case of **Spring core** and **Hibernate** it's working fine and giving desired result.
But with **Spring MVC** and **Hibernate** integration, it's giving below error

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V

If any further information is needed, please put in the comment section. I will provide the entire configuration details.

Thanks in Advance. :-)

[image: Dependency Hierarchy]

Comment: try to get dependency tree from maven of your jars `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections`, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html, there may see the conflicts

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you have both Hibernate core 5 and 3.5.6 in your dependency tree. That is probably the source of your problems

Comment: Yep... already figured out and posted in the answer section.
@pezetem and Bohuslav, thanks for your inputs

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at [Spring IO](http://platform.spring.io/platform/). It alleviates the pain of manually selecting the correct dependency versions by providing a curated list of dependency versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On removing the below dependencies from pom.xml has resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Because of this dependencies, there was conflict on the Resolved dependencies.(Refer the pic attached on the question).

**hibernate-annotations** is not required, It was dependent on older version of **hibernate-core** and **hibernate-commons-annotations**

**hibernate-commons-annotations** (version 5.0.2) is present in **hibernate-core** as a dependent jar. So it's not required to mention older version in pom.xml